# Method in importlib has same feature imp.load_source

Tags: python

How to using imp.load_source in python 3.4+

I use `imp.load_source` as follows:

```py
setting = imp.load_source('setting', '/home/abc/setting.py')
print(setting.color) # get attribute color in setting file
```

but in python 3.4+, `imp` module has deprecated and change to use `importlib` module

I tried using `SourceFileLoader`

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

setting = SourceFileLoader('setting', '/home/abc/setting.py')
print(setting.color)
```

but output

```
AttributeError: 'SourceFileLoader' object has no attribute color
```

What method in `importlib` has the same feature `imp.load_source`?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? If you really want to execute code from aribitrary source files, you might want to just use `open` to read the text and `exec` to execute it. But that's an extremely uncommon use case, and one that is going to be a security vulnerability far more often than not.

Comment: If you just want to parse *data* using Python semantics, you might want `ast.literal_eval` instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden, I have setting.py have constant variable, I want to load them to use. Follow documentation from python ```imp``` move to ```importlib```, but I can't see any method same ```load_source``` in ```importlib```

Comment: From https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/214 can you give the following a try: `from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader; mymodule = SourceFileLoader('modname', '/path/to/file.py').load_module()`

Comment: @Peter: For what it's worth, it sounds like you have the security vulnerability I was describing: you might *expect* that your `settings.py` file only contains "constant variables" but you don't *know* that, and you can't tell without executing code, which could do anything that your program has the power to do. This means that your `settings.py` file is not *data*, it's *code*, and the safe way to deploy code is to make it a part of one of your application's packages.

Comment: @DanielPryden, I'm a newbie and I don't know _security vulnerability_ meaning, could you tell me more details or suggest  me some books about security.